# parent window iframe element trigger click by simple JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe

need to trigger click event by simple javascript in  parent window's iframe element.

***parent window***

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
    <title>Main window</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe scrolling="auto" src="html_test.php"></iframe>
        <button onclick='window.open("child.html")'>Open window</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

***child window***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.opener.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].document.getElementById('main_tab').click();
</script>
```

but onload child window get this javascript error :

```
TypeError: window.opener.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].document is undefined
```

and in file `html_test.php` div element `main_tab` is alredy there.

html_test.php html is :

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>test iframe</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li id="main_tab" onclick="alert('test click')"></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: window.opener.document.getElementsByTagName(...)[0].`contentDocument`

Comment: thnks @gp i got this error :::: `TypeError: window.opener.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].document is undefined`

Comment: document is not valid property on iframe element. use contentDocument instead.

Comment: @gp i use this `window.opener.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument.getElementById('main_tab').click();` but i got this error `contentDocument is null`

Comment: not sure then. By the way html5 `postMessage` would be much cleaner for cross frame communication. Give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your opener window is form ifream page, so simply do this code

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('main_tab').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your secondary page (that loads into the `iframe`) is faulty.  It needs a `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` at the very least, and possibly a `DOCTYPE` declaration at the top.  Also, in my experimenting with your code (in FireFox) I had trouble with `window.opener` and needed to use `window.parent` instead.  You definitely need to use `contentDocument` instead of `document`.  For me, the errors went away after making those changes.